# Dynamic ListView issue on Android

Tags: android, listview, dynamic

Currently I am working on an Android app and use parse as backend where I have created a `ListView` of  nearby places dynamically. But I face the following design issue: When the user clicks on a place, a view must appear under the clicked item.

And I have faced a problem with grouping the place, as you can see in figure 1, there are many branches for HSBC bank. In which case they are under HSBC.

I have tried expandable ListView before, but it does not give much customization for child view , just simple one.

my BaseAdapter:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import com.parse.ParseGeoPoint;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.ViewManager;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    // Declare Variables
    Context context;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    //ImageLoader imageLoader;
    private List<AnywallPost> AnywallPostlist = null;
    private ArrayList<AnywallPost> arraylist;

    public ListViewAdapter(Context context,
            List<AnywallPost> AnywallPostlist) {
        this.context = context;
        this.AnywallPostlist = AnywallPostlist;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.arraylist = new ArrayList<AnywallPost>();
        this.arraylist.addAll(AnywallPostlist);

    }

    public class ViewHolder {
        TextView distance;
        TextView name;

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return AnywallPostlist.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return AnywallPostlist.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder holder;
        final View row=view;

        if (view == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.user_custom, null);
            // Locate the TextViews in listview_item.xml
            holder.distance = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.disView);
            holder.name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.nameView);


            view.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }
        // Set the results into TextViews

        holder.name.setText(AnywallPostlist.get(position).getText());
        holder.distance.setText(AnywallPostlist.get(position).getDis());


        //Listen for ListView Item Click
        view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                Toast.makeText(context,AnywallPostlist.get(position).getText(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


            }
        });
        return view;
    }

}
```

.

```
import com.parse.ParseClassName;
import com.parse.ParseGeoPoint;
import com.parse.ParseObject;
import com.parse.ParseQuery;
import com.parse.ParseUser;

/**
 * Data model for a post.
 */
@ParseClassName("places")
public class AnywallPost extends ParseObject {

  public String getText() {
    return getString("text");
  }

  public void setText(String value) {
    put("text", value);
  }

public String getBank() {
    return getString("bank");
  }

  public void setBank(String value) {
    put("bank", value);
  }

  public ParseUser getUser() {
    return getParseUser("user");
  }

  public void setUser(ParseUser value) {
    put("user", value);
  }


  public String getType()
  {
    return getString("type");  
  }

  public void setType(String value)
  {
    put("type",value);
  }

  public ParseGeoPoint getLocation() {
    return getParseGeoPoint("location");
  }

  public void setLocation(ParseGeoPoint value) {
    put("location", value);
  }


  public String getDis()
  {
    return getString("dis");  
  }

  public void setdis(String value)
  {
    put("dis",value);
  }

  public static ParseQuery<AnywallPost> getQuery() {
    return ParseQuery.getQuery(AnywallPost.class);
  }
}
```

.

```
switch (getItemViewType(position)) {
            case 0:
                Bank bank = (Bank) getItem(position);
                holder.name.setText(bank.name);
                String str = String.valueOf(bank.numBranches);
                holder.cn.setText(str);
                imageLoader.DisplayImage(bank.image,
                        holder.logo);
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "img"+bank.image,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                // ... set the image here
                // ... set the number of branches here
                break;
            case 1:
                branch = (AnywallPost) getItem(position);
                holder.name.setText(branch.getText());
                holder.distance.setText(branch.getDis());
                holder.b.setText(branch.getbranch());
                imageLoader.DisplayImage(branch.getimg(),
                        holder.logo);
                break;
            case 2:
                branch = (AnywallPost) getItem(position);
                holder.name.setText(branch.getText());
                holder.distance.setText(branch.getDis());
                holder.b.setText(branch.getbranch());
                imageLoader.DisplayImage(branch.getimg(),
                        holder.logo);
                // ... set values for all the expanded view widgets too
                break;
        }
```

I have used this code to get image from parse and I add it to AnywallPost

```
ParseFile image = (ParseFile) country.get("image");

AnywallPost map = new AnywallPost();

map.setimg(image.getUrl());
```

then, I used this code to load the image and it worked fine

```
imageLoader.DisplayImage(AnywallPostlist.get(position).getimg(),
                holder.logo);
```

Comment: Are you familiar with how the `Adapter` methods `getViewTypeCount()` and `getItemViewType()` work?

Comment: @krislarson yes I do. can you help me ?

Comment: I have an idea, I'm busy right now but I will post an answer in about an hour

Comment: @krislarson thkx I will be waiting for you

Comment: You commented `ExpandableListView` "does not give much customization for child view", can you explain what you meant by that?  Did the concept of the `ExpandableListView` fit in with your app?

Comment: @krislarson would you please check my BaseAdapter. regarding Expandablelistview ,I meant that the child view is simple.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my idea:

You will have two layouts, a brief one with the name & distance, and an expanded one with the name & distance plus all the details.

The brief layout will have a view type of 0, and the expanded layout will have a view type of 1.

When you click on the item, you set a flag in the list model to indicate that the view has switched from brief view to long view.  So you should see the view switch.  If you click on an expanded view, it will revert to brief view.

I don't have a way to test this, but here is how I think the code will look:

```
public class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    // Declare Variables
    Context context;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    //ImageLoader imageLoader;
    private List<AnywallPost> AnywallPostlist = null;
    private ArrayList<AnywallPost> arraylist;

    /** this array holds a flag for each item to show if it is in brief view more or expanded view mode*/
    private boolean[] expandedView;

    public ListViewAdapter(Context context,
            List<AnywallPost> AnywallPostlist) {
        this.context = context;
        this.AnywallPostlist = AnywallPostlist;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.arraylist = new ArrayList<AnywallPost>();
        this.arraylist.addAll(AnywallPostlist);

        this.expandedView = new boolean[AnywallPostlist.size()];
    }

    public class ViewHolder {
        TextView distance;
        TextView name;
        // ... add all your expanded view fields here too
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return AnywallPostlist.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return 2; // brief & expanded
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return expandedView[position] ? 1 : 0;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return AnywallPostlist.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder holder;
        final View row=view;

        if (view == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            int layout =  expandedView[position] ? R.layout.user_custom_expanded : R.layout.user_custom;
            view = inflater.inflate(layout, parent, false);
            // Locate the TextViews in listview_item.xml
            holder.distance = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.disView);
            holder.name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.nameView);

            if (expandedView[position]) {
                // ... locate all the expanded view widgets too
            }

            view.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            // because the view type is determined by expandedView[position], the correct layout will be recycled here
            holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }
        // Set the results into TextViews

        holder.name.setText(AnywallPostlist.get(position).getText());
        holder.distance.setText(AnywallPostlist.get(position).getDis());

        if (expandedView[position]) {
            // ... set all the values for your expanded view too
        }

        //Listen for ListView Item Click
        view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                if (expandedView[position]) {
                    // this is expanded view so toggle it back to brief view
                    expandedView[position] = false;
                } else {
                    // clear any expanded views elsewhere
                    expandedView = new boolean[AnywallPostlist.size()];
                    // toggle brief view to expanded
                    expandedView[position] = true;
                }

                // forces the ListView to refresh and convert the brief view into an expanded view and vice versa.
                ListViewAdapter.this.notifyDataSetChanged();
                // Toast.makeText(context,AnywallPostlist.get(position).getText(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

        if (expandedView[position]) {
            // ... add all your event listeners for the expanded view widgets
        }

        return view;
    }

}
```

You can also add a toggle button with expand/collapse indicator to the view to control the expand/collapse so you don't click anywhere on the view to change it.

You can do this with an `ExpandableListView` if you want, you just need to change to an `ExpandableListAdapter` and do your layouts a little differently.

Comment: thank you so much it's working. but I have question , as you can see in figure one all the branches for instance HSBC bank will group together. is it possible to do it in android ? and how to do it ?!

Comment: I was guessing that your fragment had a TextView at the top for the bank name, and that the AnywallPosts were all the locations of the branches that went into a ListView underneath the bank name's TextView.  Is that what you have?  Right now you have a _homogenous_ list (every item is an AnywallPost).  You can also mix all your banks and locations together into one list (_heterogenous_).  The logic for that is a little more complicated, but very doable.  A ListView just asks an adapter, "What's at position _n_?"  and you can tell it anything you want.

Comment: let me explain the design, the design is for IOS , I try to make it for android so I made slider menu which has many fragments such as : bank ,teleccom and more. when the user click on bank the nearby places which stored in parse should be displayed. first row : bank name. second row: bank branch and when click on branch the details should be displayed for the user. in case there are many branches for the same bank it should be all under that bank.

Comment: Okay, so for your list of AnywallPosts, are they all branches of the same bank, or all different banks mixed in?

Comment: I'll have to change my answer.  Please update your question to include the data structure of the AnywallPost.  I don't really know much about Parse, so keep that in mind when you add to your question.  I think Parse does everything in JSON.  --- So now we have a heterogeneous list.  The new strategy is to extract the bank names and figure out where they go in the list, so that the bank views and branch views are interspersed.

Comment: check I have enclosed AnywallPost class it just get and set methods

Comment: thank you for effort. but I have one question I used google direction api to get the duration so I want to set the value of the expandable view , my app crash but I set value of the normal view it work. do you have any idea ?

Comment: i used getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
         int p=0;
         if (expandedView[p]) {
         holder.val.setText(duration);
         }
        }
       });

Comment: WIthout seeing the full code and the stack trace in logcat, it's hard to say exactly what happened.

Comment: I added a new answer; please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code to make a heterogeneous list:

Take a really good look at the constructor to see how I divided up the branches by bank them strung them all together into one big list.

The list is just an `Object` array, so you figure out what the item is like this:

If it's a `Bank`, then well, it's a bank.

If it's an `AnywallPost` and `expandedView[position] == false` then it's a branch, brief view

If it's an `AnywallPost` and `expandedView[position] == true` then it's a branch, expanded view

```
public class Bank {
    private String name;
    private String image;   //  maybe this needs to be URL?
    private int numBranches;
}

public class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    // Declare Variables
    Context context;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    ImageLoader imageLoader;
    private Object[] masterList;

    /** this array holds a flag for each item to show if it is in brief view more or expanded view mode*/
    private boolean[] expandedView;

    public ListViewAdapter(Context context,
                           List<AnywallPost> AnywallPostlist) {
        this.context = context;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

        /*
         * Phase I -- get list of banks and organize the branches by bank
         */
        int count = 0;
        List<String bankNames = new ArrayList<String>();
        List<Bank> banks = new ArrayList<Bank>();
        Map<String, Bank> bankMap = new HashMap<String, Bank>();
        Map<String, List<AnywallPost>> mappedBranches = new HashMap<String, List<AnywallPost>>();

        Bank bank = null;
        List<AnywallPost> branches = null;

        for (AnywallPost branch : AnywallPostlist) {

            // have we started a branch list for this bank?
            if  (! bankNames.contains(branch.getBank())) {  // no we haven't

                // remember the bank name
                bankNames.add(branch.getBank());

                // init a new Bank
                bank = new Bank();
                bank.name = branch.getBank();
                bank.image = branch.getImg();  // if this is URL make image in Bank a URL
                banks.add(bank);
                bankMap.put(bank.name, bank);
                count++;

                // create a list for this bank's branches and index it by bank
                branches = new ArrayList<AnywallPost>();
                mappedBranches.put(branch.getBank(), branches);

            } else {   // yes we have

                // get the bank for this name
                // this fixes the problem with the branch counts
                bank = bankMap.get(branch.getBank());

                // get the branch list we already created for this bank
                branches = mappedBranches.get(branch.getBank());
            }

            // remember the branch for this bank
            branches.add(branch);
            count++;

            // increment the number of branches for this bank
            bank.numBranches++;
        }

        /*
         * Phase II -- sort the banks and branches
         */

        // ... here you can order the banks by name, branches by distance, etc.

        /*
         * Phase III -- create the mixed list
         */
        int index = 0;
        masterList = new Object[count];

        for (Bank bank : banks) {

            // append a bank to the list
            masterList[index] = bank;
            index++;

            for (AnywallPost branch : mappedBranches.get(bank.name)) {

                // append a branch to the list
                masterList[index] = branch;
                index++;
            }
        }

        this.expandedView = new boolean[count];
    }

    public class ViewHolder {
        TextView distance;
        TextView name;
        ImageView logo;
        // ... add all your expanded view fields here too
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return masterList.length;
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return 4; // bank brief, bank expanded, branch brief & branch expanded
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return masterList[position];
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if (getItem(position) instanceof Bank) {
            return expandedView[position] ? 1 : 0;
        }
        return expandedView[position] ? 3 : 2;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder holder;
        final View row=view;

        if (view == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            int layout =  0;
            switch (getItemViewType(position)) {
                case 0:
                    layout = R.layout.bank_brief;
                    break;
                case 1:
                    layout = R.layout.bank_expanded;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    layout = R.layout.branch_brief;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    layout = R.layout.branch_expanded;
                    break;
            }
            view = inflater.inflate(layout, parent, false);

            switch (getItemViewType(position)) {
                case 0:
                    holder.name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.nameView);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    holder.name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.nameView);
                    // ... locate all the bank expanded view widgets too
                    break;
                case 2:
                    holder.name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.nameView);
                    holder.distance = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.disView);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    holder.name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.nameView);
                    holder.distance = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.disView);
                    // ... locate all the expanded view widgets too
                    break;
            }

            view.setTag(holder);

        } else {
            // because the view type is determined by expandedView[position], the correct layout will be recycled here
            holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }

        AnywallPost branch = null;
        switch (getItemViewType(position)) {
            case 0:
                Bank bank = (Bank) getItem(position);
                holder.name.setText(bank.name);
                imageLoader.DisplayImage(bank.image, holder.logo);
                // ... set the number of branches here
                break;
            case 1:
                holder.name.setText(bank.name);
                imageLoader.DisplayImage(bank.image, holder.logo);
                // ... set the number of branches here
                break;
            case 1:
                branch = (AnywallPost) getItem(position);
                holder.name.setText(branch.getText());
                holder.distance.setText(branch.getDis());
                break;
            case 2:
                branch = (AnywallPost) getItem(position);
                holder.name.setText(branch.getText());
                holder.distance.setText(branch.getDis());
                // ... set values for all the expanded view widgets too
                break;
        }

        //Listen for ListView Item Click
        view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                if (expandedView[position]) {
                    // this is expanded view so toggle it back to brief view
                    expandedView[position] = false;
                } else {
                    // clear any expanded views elsewhere
                    expandedView = new boolean[expandedView.length];
                    // toggle brief view to expanded
                    expandedView[position] = true;
                }

                if (getItem(position) instanceof AnywallPost) { // only for branches
                    // AnywallPost branch = (AnywallPost) getItem(position);
                    // Toast.makeText(context, branch.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

                // forces the ListView to refresh and convert the brief view into an expanded view and vice versa.
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });

        if (expandedView[position]) {
            // ... add all your event listeners for the expanded view widgets
        }

        return view;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks it's working. but I want to make slight changes that bank layout which the first contains logo and number of branches as well it can toggle. and the rest same no changes. Highly appreciated :)

Comment: I tried to add logo to first row , but my app crash because of string cann't be cast to AnywallPost. I add these lines branch = (AnywallPost) getItem(position); imageLoader.DisplayImage(branch.getimg(),
                holder.logo);

Comment: To do this you should have another object to hold the bank name, image, and number of branches.  I added this to the code.  For the toggle, you can adapt the onClick() code so that it works for the bank as well as the branch.

Comment: sorry I still cann't set the image , look at the end of my question I have enclosed my code where I got null value when I used banks.image but I have tried to view the value in toast and it return url.

Comment: for the count variable it working fine but when i had palces when three branches it give me 1 value and the places bellow that place with one bracnch it give me 3 values.Moreover ,I tried to adjust the onlick but does not work , fist time only the first layout must be appeared.

Comment: I changed the code to fix the problem with the number of branches and add an expanded view for the bank.  This code isn't going to be perfect because I can't see all your application code but I tried to give you enough to solve the problem of displaying everything in one list and being able to expand the views.  You will need to take this code and fix it up to get it to work the way you want.

Comment: Thank you very much , highly appreciated. sorry for the late reply I was bust during the last week.